# auto rename of filename if already exist php code

Tags: php

**upload.php**

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="uploader.php" method="POST">
Choose a file: <input name="uploadedfile" type="file" /><br />
Choose a file1: <input name="uploadedfile1" type="file" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
</form>
```

[image]

*image of the form upload.php*

**uploader.php**

```
mysql_select_db("test");


$target_path = "uploads/" . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);
$currentfile = $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']; 
$target_path1 = "upload1/" . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile1']['name']);
$currentfile1 = basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile1']['name']); 


$dbfiles = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM new WHERE amount='$currentfile' || amount='$currentfile1'");
if(mysql_num_rows($dbfiles) > 0 )
{ 

//what code should i place here??    

}
else
{
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path))
        {
                echo "file1: ".$_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']."<br>";
                $file1 = basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);
                mysql_query("insert into new (amount) values('$file1')");   
        }
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile1']['tmp_name'], $target_path1))
        {
                echo "file2: ".basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile1']['name']);
                $file2 = basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile1']['name']);
                mysql_query("insert into new (amount) values('$file2')");   
        }
}
```

what code should i need to place inside of this if condition `if(mysql_num_rows($dbfiles) > 0 ){ }` so that if the filename of the file that was uploaded was already exist, the file should change its filename automatically for example there was abc.jpg existing, then some one upload a new file but the name and type is same as abc.jpg.. then the newly file must be, abc_1.jpg... and if some one upload as same as abc.jpg, the name should be abc_2.jpg..
abc_1.jpg must be the name that will save to the mysql, and abc_1.jpg must the file that will save to the prepared folder.. thx

i get the idea and code here http://www.tizag.com/phpT/fileupload.php?MAX_FILE_SIZE=100000&uploadedfile=NeroMediaHub._63C8A7B0BBE5459F9AC436392B2FF50D.exe

Comment: Make it two separate `if` statements instead of an `if/elseif`. If file 1 uploads, file 2 will NOT because it won't need to evaluate the `elseif` condition

Comment: You realize that only the `if` ***or*** the `elseif` will be processed? Only one branch can be active (actually the condition is where something happens).

Comment: yeah a sec ago after posting the question, i try changing the ifelse to if only, and it works(im not looking at ur message guys ^_^)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php
$target_path = "uploads/" . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']); 
$target_path1 = "uploads/" . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile1']['name']); 

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). 
    " has been uploaded";
}
else{
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile1']['tmp_name'], $target_path1)) {
    echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile1']['name']). 
    " has been uploaded";
}
else{
    echo "There was an error uploading the file1, please try again!";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Test with something like this...

```
<?php
    $target_path = "uploads/" . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);
    $target_path1 = "uploads/" . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile1']['name']);
    $file_saved = false;

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path))
    {
        echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'])." has been uploaded";
        $file_saved = true;
    }
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile1']['tmp_name'], $target_path1))
    {
        echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile1']['name']). 
" has been uploaded";
        $file_saved = true;
    }
    if (!$file_saved)
    {
        echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
    }
?>
```

Comment: I guess we all came to the same conclusion at the same time... =P